# Azure data explore markup and storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I have a question that keeps bugging me and I cannot find the answer on Microsoft website.

I am interested in implementing a azure data explorer, so I am trying to figure out the pricing of this resource. When I head to the azure pricing page and look for data explore. I see there are 2 pricing column. One for the VM and one for the `Markup`. This is one of the point that is confusing me. What is exactly this `Markup`? I don't fully understand the use of it and why is there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [`Frequently asked questions`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-explorer/#resources) section:

> **What is a Azure Data Explorer Markup?**
>
> We charge Azure Data Explorer Markup for fast data ingestion, caching,
> querying and manageability capability of Azure Data Explorer. The
> charge is directly proportional to the number of engine vCores in the
> Azure Data Explorer cluster.

The way I understand it is that you get some resources (like VMs etc.) provisioned for you when you set up an Azure Data Explorer cluster. Markup is for the additional services (like the ones mentioned above) that Microsoft provides along with these resources.